# Можно ли полноценно использовать C++ класс в C# через DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Ну вот допустим имею класс С++:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    _declspec(dllexport) void func()
    {
        std::cout << "call func\n";
    }
    _declspec(dllexport) static void func2()
    {
        std::cout << "call func\n";
    }
    int a;
    std::string str;
};
```

Я хочу полноценно с ним работать. Создавать экземпляр класса, вызывать метод `func()`, через имя класса вызывать метод `func2()`, присваивать переменным `a` и `str` значения. Возможно ли такое сделать? Если да, то как?

P.S. хочу использовать `Qt` в `C#`

Comment: C# позволяет использовать только С интерфейс.

Comment: Напрямую - нет, нельзя. | Можно попробовать написать обёртку на C++/CLI.

Comment: Что именно из Qt хотите использовать? Возможно, есть готовая замена в .NET.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне не надо `C++/CLI`. Я не хочу ограничивать возможности `Qt`

Comment: @Lofectr: А в чём вы видите ограничение? C++/CLI — надмножество C++, нативные классы там прекрасно работают.

Comment: @VladD разве он кроссплатформенный?

Comment: @Lofectr: А, вы хотите кросс-платформенный UI? То есть BLL и модели на C#, а UI на Qt? Понимаю. Нет, вроде бы C++/CLI не портировали ещё на другие платформы.

Comment: @VladD почему сразу UI? Просто функции.

Comment: @Lofectr: А что там такого, что .NET не умеет? Или просто много legacy-кода? Я бы переписал на .NET всё, кроме числомолотилок, и сделал тонкие plain C-интерфейсы (которые по идее кроссплатформенные или почти такие).